# Jquery selection of tags

Tags: jquery

First time question.

I have a div class named "leftbox".

Inside "leftbox" I have a paragraph and a span tag nested in it.

When I mouse enter an image (class named "push"), I want the paragraph tags inside leftbox to fade out, but leave the span tags visible.

Here is the HTML for "leftbox".

```
<html>
<body>
<img class="push" src="images/seed1.jpg"></a>
<div class="leftbox">
<p>lorem ispum dolor sit ameti conse <span>this seed is your</span> etur ad ipisicing   elit sed loeiusim</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my attempt to perform this event

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".push").mouseenter(function(){
$("p").fadeOut(1000);
});
});
</script
```

Thank you for your help and sharing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the text you want to hide inside some *span* tags and then "animate" those elements into transparency then you should observe the desired effect.

```
<p>
  <span class="fadeable">lorem ispum dolor sit ameti conse</span>
  <span>this seed is your</span>
  <span class="fadeable">etur ad ipisicing  elit sed loeiusim<span>
</p>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".push").mouseenter(function () {
        $("p .fadeable").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Have a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/aQtDb/

Comment: Learned something new using jQuery. Perfect! Thank you as well

Comment: I didn't think about putting the fadeable text in it's own class. That was easy. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

This one is much much easier and doesn't need *jQuery* at all (neither any *javascript*). But it will work **only** if the `<div class="leftbox">` is **immediate** sibling of the image.
And I assumed that you want the `<span>` to fadeIn back again when the image is *unhovered*.

```
.push + .leftbox p span {
    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-out 1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity ease-out 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity ease-out 1s;
    transition: opacity ease-out 1s;
}
.push:hover + .leftbox p span {
    opacity: 0
}
```

Here's and example: **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBj4g/3/)**

---

The great advantage of this solution is the native CSS animation engine. E.g. when you *unhover* the image before the span becomes completely invisible, it will start fading-in from the same point it stopped fading-out. In *jQuery* solution it would complete the animation to `opactiy: 0` and then start fading-in back. Imagine the situation when you hover and unhover the image repeatedly 50 times in few seconds. The animation would consequently repeat itself for 50 seconds!

Comment: Super easy with CSS. Thank you for sharing!